# Visual Basic .NET Access Database Record Add

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have problem with database save changes:

```
    coon1.ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & _
    "magazyn.mdb"
     sql = "INSERT INTO magazyn   (ID_Towaru,Kod_Towaru,Nazwa_Towaru,Ilość_w_magazynie,ilość_minimalna,ALERT) VALUES ('" & jakiid & "','" & kodtowaru & "','" & nazwatowaru & "','" & iloscwmagazynie & "','" & iloscminimalna & "',0)"


    Dim MyConnection As New OleDbConnection(conn)
    Dim command1 As New OleDbCommand(sql, MyConnection)

    command1.Connection.Open()
    command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MyConnection.Close()
```

I try add new record to table `magazyn`, but when opened database with Access then I didn't see any new record related to `magazyn` in the table. But `ViewGrid` shows me this new element until I close and re-open the program.

Does someone know where the problem is?

Comment: Maybe VS is replacing the "working" copy of your database with the original (empty) one each time you run the program inside IDE.

Comment: Is jakiid  / ID_Towaru numeric? If so, do not use quotes. Is it an autonumber? If so, do not insert it. It is usually best to check that a query works in MS Access before using SQL. You would be much better off with parameters and a saved query, or at the very least, parameters.

Comment: @Remou yes ID_Towaru is a autonumber. Ok so I Try delete  this ID_Towaru from query edit: I remove ID_Towaru from query but nothing new happend

Comment: Does the query work when you run it in MS Access?

Comment: Ilość_w_magazynie and ilość_minimalna seems to be numbers. Again, numbers should not be enclosed in single quote.

Comment: SOLVED :) Adriano have rights ! Thanka mate i change a connectingstring to connect with other database and it work

Answer (score 2):

Always use parameters and not string concatenation. This rule should be followed categorically

```
sql = "INSERT INTO magazyn  " + 
       "(Kod_Towaru,Nazwa_Towaru,Ilość_w_magazynie,ilość_minimalna,ALERT) " + 
       "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,0)"
Using MyConnection As New OleDbConnection(conn)
Using command1 As New OleDbCommand(sql, MyConnection)
    command1.Connection.Open()
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kod", kodtowaru)
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naz", nazwatowaru)
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ilo", iloscwmagazynie)
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mini", iloscminimalna)
    command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

This, of course, requires that the variables used as value for the parameters are of the correct datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Please Insert This Below Coding in Module.

Imports System.Data.OleDb
Module Module1

```
Public OleCn As New OleDbConnection()

Public Function StrConnection() As String

    StrConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\BackUp\Testing.Accdb;"

    Return StrConnection
End Function
```

After This Insert the Below Coding in Save Button.

Dim msg As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Save this Record? ", "Response", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

```
    If (msg = vbYes) Then

        If RequiredEntry() = True Then
            Return
        End If

        Try
            With OleCn
                If .State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                    .ConnectionString = StrConnection()
                    .Open()
                End If
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

        Try

            Dim sSQL As String = "insert into Vendor values(@VendorCode,@VendorName,@Address,@City,@LandPhone,@Mobile,@EmailID,@Balance)"

            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, OleCn)

            'VendorCode
            Dim VendorCode As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@VendorCode", OleDbType.VarChar, 10)
            VendorCode.Value = txtVendorCode.Text.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(VendorCode)

            'VendorName
            Dim VendorName As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@VendorName", OleDbType.VarChar, 25)
            VendorName.Value = txtVendorName.Text.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(VendorName)

            'Address
            Dim Address As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@Address", OleDbType.VarChar, 50)
            Address.Value = txtAddress.Text.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Address)

            'City
            Dim City As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@City", OleDbType.VarChar, 25)
            City.Value = txtCity.Text.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(City)

            'LandPhone
            Dim LandPhone As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@LandPhone", OleDbType.VarChar, 50)
            LandPhone.Value = txtLandPhone.Text.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(LandPhone)


            'Mobile
            Dim Mobile As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@Mobile", OleDbType.VarChar, 15)
            Mobile.Value = txtMobile.Text.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Mobile)

            'EmailID
            Dim EmailID As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@EmailID", OleDbType.VarWChar, 25)
            EmailID.Value = txtEmailID.Text.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(EmailID)


            'Balance
            Dim Balance As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@Balance", OleDbType.VarWChar, 10)
            Balance.Value = txtBalance.Text.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(Balance)

            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() Then

                OleCn.Close()
                MessageBox.Show("New Record is Added Successfully.", "Record Saved")
                Call clear()

            Else

                MsgBox("Record Addition Failed ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Addition Failed")

                Return
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Data Error")
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    End If
```